# How to implement the state value function?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I'm watching the Berkely CS 294 course about Deep Reinforcement Learning. However, I meet some troubles on the assignment. I tried to implement the equation below. I think it is quite simple but I failed to obtain the expected result as showed in the comments. There must be something that I misunderstood. Details are shown in the code below.  Can anyone help?

[state value function http://quicklatex.com/cache3/4b/ql_a4e0ff64c86ce8e3e60f94cfb9fc4b4b_l3.png](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/4b/ql_a4e0ff64c86ce8e3e60f94cfb9fc4b4b_l3.png)

Here is my code:

```
def compute_vpi(pi, P, R, gamma):
    """
    :param pi: a deterministic policy (1D array: S -> A)
    :param P: the transition probabilities (3D array: S*A*S -> R)
    :param R: the reward function (3D array: S*A*S -> R)
    :param gamma: the discount factor (scalar)
    :return: vpi, the state-value function for the policy pi
    """
    nS = P.shape[0]
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    ############## Here is what I wrote ######################
    vpi = np.zeros([nS,])
    for i in range(nS):
        for j in range(nS):
            vpi[i] += P[i, pi[i], j] * (R[i, pi[i], j] + gamma*vpi[j])
    ##########################################################
    # raise NotImplementedError()
    assert vpi.shape == (nS,)
    return vpi


pi0 = np.zeros(nS,dtype='i')
compute_vpi(pi0, P_rand, R_rand, gamma)

# Expected output:
# array([ 5.206217  ,  5.15900351,  5.01725926,  4.76913715,  5.03154609,
#         5.06171323,  4.97964471,  5.28555573,  5.13320501,  5.08988046])
```

What I got:

```
array([ 0.61825794,  0.67755819,  0.60497582,  0.30181986,  0.67560153,
    0.88691815,  0.73629922,  1.09325453,  1.15480849,  1.21112992])
```

Some Init code:

```
nr.seed(0) # seed random number generator
nS = 10
nA = 2
# nS: number of states
# nA: number of actions
R_rand = nr.rand(nS, nA, nS) # reward function
# R[i,j,k] := R(s=i, a=j, s'=k), 
# i.e., the dimensions are (current state, action, next state)
P_rand = nr.rand(nS, nA, nS) 
# P[i,j,k] := P(s'=k | s=i, a=j)
# i.e., dimensions are (current state, action, next state)

P_rand /= P_rand.sum(axis=2,keepdims=True) # normalize conditional probabilities
gamma = 0.90
```

Comment: You might want to try telling us what you expected to see, and what you saw...

Comment: I added some explanation, it is about a equation named value function in reinforcement learning, I thought it was a quite simple and basic conception, however the wrong output is telling me that I'm wrong -,-

Comment: Why are you summing over s (`i`) as well as s' (`j`) when the given function you are trying to implement only sums over s?  (Also, your comments state you are returning a function, but you are actually returning an array...)

Comment: Maybe some reference links/notes so those who didn't attend that specific course (and still remember anything) can get where you are? In particular, a formula without notes what it is and what its parts are has no meaning whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you all, I found the solution in assignment part2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the assignment 2 provided the solution, if someone else is learning this course online and meet some troubles, try to find some tips from the next assignment.